# How can i call editPost controller after an observer(checkout_onepage_controller_success_action) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping-address

I have to save the `account edit` with customer `default shipping address` details. After the successful order placement.

I have created the observer but not sure how to call `editPost` of the customer from that execute method.

```
<?php
 namespace YX\Customer\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class OrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    if ($shippingAddress) {
        $firstname =  $shippingAddress->getFirstname();
        $secondname =  $shippingAddress->getLastname();
        $telephone =  $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
    }

 }
}
```

Now I need to send these 3 parameter `$firstname`, `$secondname`, `$telephone` to `editPost` controller.

How can to achieve it.

My code looks something like that

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();

    if ($shippingAddress) {
        $firstname =  $shippingAddress->getFirstname();
        $secondname =  $shippingAddress->getLastname();
        $telephone =  $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
        $customer->setData('firstname', $firstname);
        $customer->setData('lastname', $secondname);
        $customer->setData('mobile', $telephone);
        $customer->save();
    }
```

Comment: from an event call, `account edit`  action is not a good idea. Why you need this  editpost

Comment: I need to update the customer edit form by default shipping address data first , last name and phone , everytime Shipping address changes after order place I need to change the data customer form edit

Comment: Means you want to change the customer default  Shipping address( first , last name and phone)  by  Order Shipping address  (first , last name and phone)?

Comment: No, I want to take the default shipping address first last name and save it to customer edit form which is editPost controller , default shipping address will remain as it is , default shipping address is address book and I want to reflect the changes in customer edit form

Comment: Your comment seems confusion.`I want to take the default shipping address first last name and save it to customer edit form which is formEdit , default shipping address will remain as it is`.Clarify it

Comment: In layman terms, I need to update the first last name and telephone phone of customer edit and that values would be from default shipping address which customer creates or updates in checkout process . So we are not modifying default shipping address

Comment: And from an event all calling editPost controller why it's a bad idea ?

Comment: its means you want to update customer first name and last name using first & the last name which in enter during order creatation at checkout page?

Comment: @AmitBera yes exactly, we have a functionality to enter the shipping address at the time of checkout which is saved in My Account Address book and whenever a user places an order or creates a new shipping address I just need to use that updated shipping address values and pouplate it tp customer edit form

Answer (score 1):

In your

> Vendor\ModuleName\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="custom_frontend_observer" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\AfterCheckout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In your

> Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\AfterCheckout.php

```
 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class AfterCheckout implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customer        = $customer;
    }

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $customer   = $this->customer->create()->load($customerId);
    $customer->setData('firstname',$order->getFirstName );
    $customer->setData('lastname', $order->getLastName);
    $customer->setData('mobile',$order->getMobile );
    $customer->save();

}
```

Comment: But I only need to save the first name and last name and phone number not whole address as customer edit form doesn't, have that many fields as the address book and I am not sure if I get default shipping address from that $order->getData('address')

Comment: check my update answer

Comment: how do you find the setData keys, like when i wrote the code before your answer , i wrote customer->setData('telephone',$order->getMobile );

Comment: I have updated my code, see my updated question

Comment: if you have access to your Database find table `customer_entity` you will get All keys there